# Post Files to ASPNetCore API IFormFile Type

Tags: flutter, api, file, post, dio

I want to send data with files to AspNetCore api that receive files type IFormFile I tried this

```dart
    Dio dioFile = Dio(
        BaseOptions(
          baseUrl: baseUrl,
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ${APIVariables.token}',
          },
        ),
      );

    dioFile.post(
    url,
    data: {
          "id": complaint.id,
          "title": complaint.title,
          "files": complaint.files
              .map((file) => base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync()))
              .toList(),
        };
    );
```

but it shows dio error: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400].

**How can I solve that and is there another better method to do that?**

**And if I want to send files using MultipartFile how can I do that and what api specialist should do to handle my post?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the image file then,
It should look like this.

```
    String fileName = imageFile.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "image-param-name": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
        imageFile.path,
        filename: fileName,
        contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpeg"), //important
      ),
    });
```

If without this line.

```
contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpeg")
```

Maybe it will cause an error: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400] Exception

You must confirm the correct contentType to work it as expected

And get MediaType in this package: [http_parser](https://pub.dev/packages/http_parser)

Comment: I tried that but it's not working

Comment: It shows DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [415]

Comment: For me the solution was, just set the contentType header like this:

Dio dio = new Dio();
dio.options.contentType = Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType;

Search for your type of content.